# How to get text following label in Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, text, label

In this HTML, there is no uniquely identified wrapper. If the voice number and/or the fax number is there then the Phone Numbers: label will always be there. If there is no number then the associated label will never be there. If there is a number then the associated label will always be there, but the number will change:

```
<p>
<label>Phone Numbers:</label>
<br>
<label>Voice Number:</label>
" (321) 456-7890"
<br>
<label>Fax Number:</label>
" (123) 456-7890"
</p>
```

I want to get the text (the numbers) following the voice and fax labels.

I used:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//label[text() = "Voice Number:"]')
```

and

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//label[text() = "Fax Number:"]')
```

to find the labels but I want to get the text (the numbers) following the labels. I found plenty of direction on how to get the text *of* a label, but nothing that worked in this situation on how to get the text *following* a label. What code should I be using to get the text following the label in this situation? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fax itself is not the text of your `label`, it's text of parent element. So, you need to parse text of parent element get fax number.

If parent doesn't have unique attribute, you can:

1. search by `label`
2. get it's parent
3. get parent text
4. split it by your search term
5. get the last array element (it would be your fax number)

```py
search_text = 'Fax Number:'
fax = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//label[text() = "{search_text}"]/..')
fax_text = fax.text.split(search_text)[-1]
```

You can test it there:

```py
url = "https://inputnum.w3spaces.com/saved-from-Tryit-2023-09-05.html"
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: I like this solution better than mine because it is shorter.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try to look for the upper level element that is wrapping both the `<label>Fax Number:</label>` and `"(123) 456-7890"`?

For example:

```
<div id='FaxNo'>
    <label>Fax Number:</label>
    "(123) 456-7890"
<div/>
```

Then, you can try to find the `<div>` element instead of the `<label>` element.

Answer (score 0):

So this seems to be working for me:

```
if driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[contains(text(), "Phone Numbers:")]'):
    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[contains(text(), "Phone Numbers:")]')
    nbrs_para = element.find_element(By.XPATH, '..').text
    nbrs = nbrs_para.split('\n')
    target = re.compile(r'^Voice Number: ')
    for item in nbrs:
        if target.search(item):
            v_nbr = item[14:]
    target = re.compile(r'^Fax Number: ')
    for item in nbrs:
        if target.search(item):
            f_nbr = item[12:]
```

The strength of this code is that it works with no wrappers and few other HTML landmarks. The weakness of this code is that it seems like kludge. I regularly find here code that can only be described as logical works of art, so feel free to tighten this up.